# Filling gaps in my vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary

I know English pretty well, and I use it more than I use my native language, and I rarely have trouble conveying my thoughts / ideas.

The problem is, however, that I didn't learn it in a systematic way (instead, I relied on watching lots of American shows / movies, and just conversing with people online), so I have a lot of random gaps in my vocabulary, some of which would probably make even middle schoolers laugh at me (I'm exaggerating, of course, but you get the idea).

A few weeks ago I decided to put an end to it, and started with a 4K word flash card set I found in the [Anki database](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/english), but it became cumbersome **really** fast. Only 1 out of 20-30 words is at least somewhat unclear to me, the rest is just "next, please". I thought about picking some other set, with "advanced" words or something like that, but that's not really what I'm looking for, since I'm missing relatively many basic words, which everybody knows, like, say, body parts, or sickness symptom names, etc.

What I need is a piece of software which would [continuously] test my vocabulary and detect the gaps for me + help me fill them, instead of me doing a thorough research instead, and building a custom flash card set. Does something like that exist, or should I stop dreaming and carry on with Anki?

Comment: Try [Memrise](https://www.memrise.com) and see if it helps. You may have to try several different apps to get what you want, and as you say your knowledge has unexpected holes, which may mean you need to trod over the stuff you know to get to the stuff you don't know. Good luck!

Comment: Memrise looks promising, thanks! And yeah, I guess I'll just have to start reading more literature and stop inferring word meanings from context :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for resources

Comment: @Olegs: We don't usually acquire our vocabulary by constantly referring to dictionaries while reading "literature", so I don't think you should either. It's much better to "infer word meanings from context", the way most native speakers do / did. As a general principle I'd suggest you *only* refer to dictionaries if either (a) You've no idea at all what a word means, you can't infer *anything* from context, AND the meaning seems contextually ***important***, or (b) You *thought* you knew what a word meant, but that interpretation doesn't make sense in some new context you're now reading.

Comment: Agreed. Learning by context is important and an efficient way to go. The skill is to learn "how to learn by context". Serial shows either are good since there is constant dialogue and you can hear how the word is used and pronounced. Merely hearing the same word used over and over in different situations will yield not only the meaning but also the cultural context and feeling of a word or phrase, something a dictionary can not give. It's how kids learn and anyone learning a new language is a child once more (but sometimes with the baggage of already knowing another language and culture...)

Comment: @Peter: Absolutely. I closevoted because the question is Off Topic, but I hope the mods at least leave *your* comment untouched, since the point about learning the "cultural context and feeling of a word or phrase" is incisive. Off Topic or not, questions like this *do* get asked here fairly often, and I can easily see myself closevoting the next one as a duplicate of this purely because of your comment.

Comment: DuoLingo.com could be what you're looking for

Comment: Maybe I'm just weird, but when I was little I spent a lot of time reading and referring to dictionaries.  I started reading *The Lord of the Rings* when I was six years old (and finished when I was seven), but it was hard for me to understand at that age, so I looked up a lot of things in dictionaries :-)

Comment: I agree with Peter that memrise may  have a greater selection  and even offer units of specialized vocabulary (colours, household stuff, academic, whatever.),but in general it's not a great learning tool. you will 'learn' vocabulary that you can recall on memrise, yet you won't be able to produce it in a real world context. memrise is better for reviewing words you already know, and you build that vocabulary by more exposure to real world language... in this case, try texts (not textbooks) written for whatever level you feel comfortable with and whose subject matter interests you...

Comment: ... write down words you don't know, in a sentence, with the definition. review the words every day  then every week. even writing them down will be better than typing them on memrise  which really is more like a computer game. And keep watching TV and series, like Seinfeld or the Simpsons or Friends, you'll get exposed to day-to-day English quickly. and practice speaking on Skype or Verbling. and listen to songs. try http://lyricstraining.com/ the combination of listening and writing is great!

Comment: This is a quintessential question about language learning  the kind that may not fit the SE model. It's a shame SE:ELU  isn't robust enough to be a true *language learning* site. There's always, [How to Learn any Language](http://www.how-to-learn-any-language.com/), which remains my preferred site for tips, methods, discussion, resources,  et al.

Comment: You may want to ask on [softwarerecs.se] - I actually discovered the Anki application by doing a search there.

Comment: Why is it okay to ask for a "method" (e.g. flash cards in general), but not for a software solution? For example, things like Duolingo can be genre-defining, which might even have no paper-based alternative (besides those huge and expensive language learning sets, with thick textbooks and audio tapes and whatnot, which don't really compare). Here, on ELL, I'm probably 1000% more likely to encounter somebody who has a good relevant suggestion, compared to Software Recs and alike, and this is also where people might look first.

Comment: And I have to chime in and say my vocabulary acquisition was similar to @snailboat I read a lot of advanced-for-my-age books and I still have my little red dictionary I used to figure things out (and to randomly pick words for my parent's "use one new word in conversation a day" challenge).

Comment: About looking up in a dictionary - things is, I don't really recall a time when I couldn't understand a sentence, unless it's about some advanced scientific / political / etc. subject. I keep inferring from context, and it doesn't bother me, I have no issues with **understanding** text / speech. However, sometimes I have trouble recalling the right word when I want to say / write something (especially when talking, since I can't just restructure the beginning of my sentence to fit a synonym on the fly), even though I'd probably recognize it and understand it if I saw it in a sentence.

Comment: I mentioned Software Recs, because there are already good recommendations there for language learning software, not because I was justifying a close vote. It was decided a while ago that resource requests were off-topic on the main ELL site, and should be directed to meta and possibly the thread here: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/735/ What's OK and what's not OK to ask is definitely a moving target, so view the discussion here as a good thing, and don't get too annoyed while the community sorts out how we feel about it :) Closure isn't final anyhow.

Comment: The dictionary though gives you a precision of language that is useful. Understanding the gist of something is usually good enough because most folks aren't that precise in every day speech. Read something with beautiful language that makes you really want to understand the exact nuance instead of utilitarian stuff :)

Comment: Yeah, all good, just expressing my surprise with the preference of Software Recs over ELL for this kind of question :) My impression always was that SR is geared towards purely tech questions (e.g. "which database should I use for X"), not something as specialized as "how do I expand my English vocabulary efficiently". Now that I think about it though, it makes sense. And yeah, I definitely need to read something with beautiful language :) News and blog posts are not it.

Comment: I guess people think this is off-topic here (possibly because people think this site should be EL&U lite and not ELL), but maybe it'd be on-topic on the new [Language Learning site](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) if it ever gets to public beta.

Comment: Also please keep in mind well spoken radio programs like BBC Radio 4 or National Public Radio (NPR) both of which you should be able to stream or listen to archives.  They will give you not only the vocabulary and understanding practice, but also a sense of the culture.  You will know that you are mastering your new language when you dream in it, and grasping the culture when you understand the sense of humour.